# Should I not down-vote and comment under an answer just because the user who posted it is offended by it?

Tags: discussion, comments, downvotes

See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532504/2704659

I have received a lot of "abuse" by the answering user for down-voting it and attempting to clarify my position.  The user even posted this comment, which may be deleted by the time you read this because I flagged it as "not constructive":

> Here's my thing, @rory.ap -- I get that you're smarter than me and
>   better looking and get all the girls. But if you know all this stuff,
>   why don't you spend your time helping the OP instead of obsessing over
>   someone else's post?

But I can't see anything wrong with my down-vote and comments.  Should I have not even bothered?

Comment: You are putting it on a bit thick aren't you?  Would make a bit more sense if you weren't wrong about it, those guids are hard-baked and *do* correspond with Environment.SpecialFolder.  Give him a break.

Comment: If after a couple of comments you're not getting anywhere, after ten the damage will be bigger. Just move on.

Comment: You stated your point once. The person in question has not deleted or changed his post. No point in going on anymore. If you believe the answer is not correct you can downvote it but engaging into discussions about the same thing in the comment usually don't go anywhere. This person put work into this answer. A comment by somebody who interprets the question differently will not make him change his mind easily

Comment: @Hayt: Not always, but there are exceptions where the person answering the question did genuinely misinterpret something, _and_ did accept that. Imo, there's no harm in commenting with an explanation of your downvote, as long as you're keeping it factual. Also, don't try to force it.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah I meant "longer" discussions instead of one comment. But I kind of added a similar comment to that to your answer already.

Comment: FWIW, I've had a similar issue with the same user, where they just hadn't read the question (and continued to edit their answer in ways which wouldn't address the question, despite repeated attempts to explain that a date is not the same as a time...) Some users seem to want to post something, whether it's useful or not.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: But are you better-looking than him? Do you get all the girls? (No doubt you're smarter...)

Comment: @BoltClock: No, I didn't get that praise.

Comment: @HansPassant -- So if a client provided a folder ID at runtime, how do you translate it into one of these special folder enums?  That's the crux of my debate.  Why should I give him a break, anyway?  Are you trying to dissuade me from down-voting an answer I feel is completely wrong?  At any rate, it appears I'm doing the same thing here, with you...

Comment: Feel free to downvote, just no point in making it an extended drama.  One comment is plenty.

Comment: You seem to be conflating downvoting and commenting, making them sound like one action. They're not. You can downvote and comment, or do either one, or abstain completely.

Comment: The OP has a right to be offended. By all means avail them of the opportunity to exercise that right! Freedom!

Comment: Vote on content, and comment on content, but don't comment on votes. Separate the votes from the comments entirely. They are two different things that are not related in any way. No one will know that you downvoted their post unless you tell them that you downvoted your post.

Comment: @TinyGiant I did not downvote your comment.

Comment: @Yakk You can't downvote comments

Comment: @TylerH More evidence of my honesty.

Comment: @Yakk Interestingly, that's actually a classic misdirection (saying you didn't do something that's not possible/real in order to prove your honesty/trustworthiness), so really it's dishonesty ;-) But we digress...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think it's ***great*** that you accompany your down-vote with a comment.

Not nearly enough users do so.

---

That said, there will always be users that aren't interested in what you have to say about their answer, because their answer is right, no matter what you say.

The best thing to do when you realize you're talking to a wall, is just to walk away. If a user doesn't want to hear it, there is really nothing to gain from trying to explain your downvote.

If said user decides it's time to turn to insults: Flag, and *don't respond*. They're not worth it.

Comment: "there is really nothing to gain from trying to explain your downvote" That's why most don't, and don't think of it as a problem that they don't.

Comment: @BoltClock: True, unless said user is open to other opinions. Personally, I really appreciate it when downvotes are accompanied by a comment. Maybe my answer is wrong, or maybe I missed something, who knows?

Comment: I agree with @Cerbrus here. If I disagree with a comment on my answer I usually answer to it (when edited or when not why not) but when when some comment comes back "how I am wrong" or nitpicking I usually stop further interaction because when there is resistance some comment wont change that (applies also when you comment on an answer)

Comment: Good on you both. You are more open-minded than others. Many have gotten the short end of the stick more than they'd like, though. There is not enough ocean on this planet for the salt on the Internet.

Comment: Well sometimes it can be solved by basic conversation skills. When I read a comment on an answer of mine which just starts with "No ... " it's normal that resistance goes up. Instead of just formulating the comment in a less "agressive/opposing" way. Sadly communication is not really a skill taught much.

Comment: -1 because I wanted to demonstrate that at least one more user comments when they downvote. (seriously, though, +1 for the good answer)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Except that you're supposed to comment on content, not on your votes...

Comment: @Tiny I was mimicking comments of the form "-1 because this is vulnerable to buffer overflow"

Comment: @TinyGiant: Nobody is _supposed_ to comment on anything. You are not saying one _shouldn't_ explain their downvotes, are you?

Comment: Of course I am saying that. There is absolutely no reason to explain a downvote ever. However, if you can offer a suggestion to improve a post, or a criticism on the content of the post, or would like to request clarifications, you should definitely comment on those things. But no, you should never comment on your vote itself, you should only comment about content. Telling people you downvoted their content is pointless and non-productive. Telling people how you think that their content can be improved is much more productive.

Comment: I don't completely agree, I think the fact that you voted can be relevant.

Answer (score 11):

It is perfectly fine to downvote and comment on an answer if you think it's not correct, as long as you don't offend the author. Of course politely explaining what is wrong, without name-calling, is not considered offensive.

Comment: _"...as long as you don't offend the author"_, well, if the OP for the answer is offended by a __constructive suggestion__, then, __do offend__. Even if the the answer remains unchanged, someone can read the comment and keep themselves from falling into the trap of a wrong answer. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh "Of course politely explaining what is wrong, without name-calling, is not considered offensive."

Comment: Yes, to you, to me and to most of the sensible people out here, but sadly, not to the OP. Even in that case, I'd prefer offending. Hope you get my _point_. ;)

Comment: @Gothdo It's a matter of definition. Some people actually regard something being offensive as soon as there's someone who takes offense. And, sadly, in 2016 there's almost always someone who will take offense. Now, I agree with your point - if it's reasonably polite and well-meant, it shouldn't be an offense. But still, no matter how hard you try, how well you intend and how carefully you thread. There will always be a (surprisingly large) set of people who take offense. In Swedish we have a term for them: *djävla idioter*. Yes, it means precisely what you think, haha.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: You know what's offensive? People getting offended about everything. Damn...

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm offended by the fact that you talked about people being offended. I'm also offended by me getting offended. And the circle goes on and on... In my view, it's become our national sports to be offended by anyone/anything. The most idiotic and minimal reason to get offended by wins. At least in Sweden.